# Prevent opening Visual Studio Code when click Show In Folder in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, chromium, linux-mint, file-management

I've been googling and fighting this for a half a day already.

When I download something in Google Chrome I want to go to the folder with a file. But when I press 'Show in folder' a Visual Studio Code starts instead of my Thunar. How can I fix this?

Firefox opens folders ok but Chromium, Google-Chrome and Opera kicks of Visual Studio Code.

My system is Linux Mint Tara. I've already tried some things. Like added

```
[Default Applications]
inode/directory=Thunar.desktop
```

to /home/[user]/.config/mimeapps.list

Completely removed `code.desktop` from /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache

Ran `xdg-mime default Thunar.desktop inode/directory` and the output of `xdg-mime query default inode/directory` is Thunar.desktop!!!

Even fully removed code.desktop from filesystem. Nothing worked!

Please help, this annoys me so much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is caused by `MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;` which can be found in `/usr/share/applications/code.desktop` for what I can find.

What fixed it for me is changing this line to `MimeType=text/plain;` and removing code.desktop from `/usr/share/applications/mimelist.cache`

EDIT
A more permanent solution i've found is the following.
add `inode/directory=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` to the `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` file.
After doing this make sure to the inode/directory entry is the same or not present at all in `~/.local/share/applications/mimelist.cache'` and `/usr/share/applications/mimelist.cache`

`org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` can be replaced by your preferred file explorer if you don't use Nautilus.

You might need to restart your desktop environment for the changes to apply.

Comment: I guess that helped me. But I had to restart my computer in order the changes apply. Also after that, just now, I updated the vscode and the problem was back so I had to repead everything and restart again :(

Comment: @user1278890 See latest edit, that should have fixed it more permanent. For me it worked without restarting by using xdg-mime to set default.

Comment: Well, it worked some time but everything just stopped working now. No matter what I do this stupid vscode opens for my folders. I guess I will just live with it, will have to manually open the Downloads folder or whatever folder it is from the file manager :( It affects only stupid chromium derivatives. Firefox behaves normally.

Comment: Thank you, In my case I solved with removed MimeType=inode/directory; from /usr/share/applications/code.desktop and removed code from "inode/directory" in  /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache

Answer (score 6):

The solution is simpler,
What happens is that the system orders the directory opening preferences.
Just go to the file manager > select a folder > right click > open with another application > select the file manager.
This will update the opening preferences for the directories.

Comment: Worked for me on KDE to open directories with Dolphin as this used to be before VS Code mucked up the `inode/directory` asslciation.

Comment: A small detail: remember to tick the checkbox "remember the file type association". This also worked great for me on KDE.

Answer (score 5):

Finally found! it. I had to delete

`inode/directory; /usr/share/code/code --new-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"`

line in the /etc/mailcap file. Bingo!

Chromium related browsers seems to not respect xdg settings on not full-fledged Desktop environments like i3wm which I use. Because the problem was not reproducible when I logged in with xfce4 session.